# full screen in android at runtime (no notification/status bar and app title bar)?

Tags: android

is following both lines are

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

considering I am writing this line in activity class

Comment: I believe this works. Are you asking a Yes or No question?

Answer (score -1):

hope it helps

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

Comment: we get exception when we use <pre><code>requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); </code></pre> <br>http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties

Comment: use this before setting layout(setContentView)

Comment: but I want to do it at runtime , suppose on some buttonclick